# How to create recurring Facebook events?

Tags: facebook

Is there way to create recurring facebook events? If not, is there a workaround? Is there a plugin that I can place on my website to automatically create facebook events?

Comment: I've voted to send it to facebook.stackoverflow.com, which is now the official Facebook support site.

Comment: @paulmorriss actually, facebook.stackoverflow.com is for facebook programing, it has nothing to do with using the webapp. See the related [FAQ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be workarounds/plugins, but Facebook doesn't support it natively: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210475378992333

Answer (score 0):

[FB says](https://www.facebook.com/help/479704465721993/) it's not possible to create recurring events as a profile.

> Only Pages, not personal profiles, can create recurring events.

The only way is to create a Page, when can then create recurring events as the Page.

Or, you could create the recurring events only for a group (but you'll have this [public sharing issue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/165940/create-facebook-group-event-with-public-privacy)).